# How can I go from VR to 2D mode in Unity hybrid app?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, rotation, gyroscope, google-vr

I have implemented an app to use in mobile as VR viewer of the human anatomy. It is done with the Google VR SDK and I could switch from VR mode to Fullscreen mode (hybrid app). That was before I updated to the last sdk version (v1.200.1). Now it seems the full screen mode is not longer being controlled by the sdk. I could find this:

https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/unity/guides/hybrid-apps

and this:

https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/unity/guides/magic-window

And I replicated the same but the problem is inside my VRCamera I have two UIs objects that I follow the camera and now if I try to rotate the camera this objects rotates as well and the position changes as well. I Just want to have them in the same position without rotation. Just looking to the camera as a turn it to them

Now I am trying to update the objects rotation and position in update but it seems it doesn't work. I know I can rotate the camera getting the Input.gyro but since the objects are children of the camera it seems they are moving too.

```
            reference.localRotation =
            // Allow user to drag left/right to adjust direction they're facing.
            Quaternion.Euler(0f, -dragYawDegrees, 0f) *

            // Neutral position is phone held upright, not flat on a table.
            Quaternion.Euler(90f, 0f, 0f) *

            // Sensor reading, assuming default `Input.compensateSensors == true`.
            Input.gyro.attitude *

            // So image is not upside down.
            Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 180f);
```

I hope I have explained it well

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm developing AR application with UI and some camera manipulations like zooming, rotating and so on. So I decided to make another camera(child to main camera) and set it's culling mask to "everythink" and the AR camera culling mask to nothink(so main camera's usage is only for positioning). I think you can do it the same way too.

Comment: Thank you, @KamikyIT I am actually creating another camera and trying to add the same behaviour but outside the vrcamera. I tried what you said but everytime I rotate the camera it still moves the child objects.

Comment: That's pretty hard to understand your camera behaviour. I think you should record a video, so we'll try to solution your problem :)

Comment: Well you are right. Maybe this is a different question but I am just trying to fix the position of a gameobject in front of the camera. So I have localrotation for the maincamera changing in update. And a gameobject in front (reference.transform.position + reference.transform.forward * 10) but everytime I rotate the camera the object moves away and I can´t see it anymore

Comment: Did you try setting gameobject's position in front of camera in Update()? Btw, camera.transform.forward * 10 places in 10 meters forward(that's pretty away).

Comment: Yes @KamikyIT I am doing it in Update() wich is ok meanwhile I dont rotate the camera is always in front of it. (Also 10 is ok since the object is big) But anytime I try to rotate the camera the object moves but it finally goes away the screen. There has to be a way to lock it in one position.